# How do I stop repeating the string "MCI" multiple times in a row in python?

Tags: python-3.5

I just want it to appear at the start of each trial and after it has reached a different location. Not consecutively.

import random

## while loop to loop back to the beginning

while True:
    trials=int(input("How many trials would you like to run?"))
    if trials <0:
        print("You must enter a value greater than 0.")

```
elif trials>0:
```

## for loop to print out each trials

```
    count=0
    for x in range(trials):
        count+=1
        count_trials=print("The Trial is",count)
```

## Assign each airport with a number from

```
        while True:
            airports=random.randint(1,4)

            print("MCI -> ", end="")
            if airports==1:
                airports="MCI"


            elif airports==2:

                airports="LVS"

            elif airports==3:

                airports="SEA"

            elif airports==4:
                print("HNL")
                break

            count_hops=print(airports, end=" -> ")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u need this

```
import random

trials=int(input("How many trials would you like to run?"))
if trials <0:
    print("You must enter a value greater than 0.")
elif trials>0:
    count=1

true=True       

while true==True:
    airports=random.randint(1,4)
    print("trial no. ->"+str(count))
    if count>=trials:
        true=False

    if airports==1:
        airports="MCI"

    elif airports==2:
        airports="LVS"

    elif airports==3:
        airports="SEA"

    elif airports==4:
        airports="HNL"

    count+=1

    count_hops=print("airport"+" -> "+airports)
```

if u cant understand something or its unappropriate pls add a comment